Hashing problem when migrating from PHP 5.6. to 8.3
We are migrating from PHP 5.6 / CodeIgniter 3 to PHP 8.3.4 / CodeIgniter 4. In the old version we used the below method on user registration and saved $salt and $password in the db.
$salt    = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), TRUE));
$password = hash('sha512', $data['password'] . $salt);

When user login we have used the below method
$results = $query->getRowArray();
$salted_password = hash('sha512', $password . $results['salt']);
if ($results['password'] == $salted_password) { return true; }

The new version is giving password mismatch with the existing users credentials in the DB. But it works totally fine with the new registered user.

Any idea about why is this happening?
Is the hash() function working differently in different PHP
versions?
Any suggestion to make it work with the existing users credentials?


hash() has not changed. Did you migrate the database too?

No. We are testing with the same db contents.

If it is not a data inconsistency, this would mean that both environments with identical password and salt produce different SHA-512 hashs. Is this the case and can you post test data? I cannot reproduce this for PHP 5.6 and PHP 8.3.4 (but without CodeIgniter).

Just did a pure 5.6 to 8.3 test, and as noted it is working as expected. https://3v4l.org/ashM2#v8.3.7

Can you run a sample password such as cheese through the 5.6 version and post a sample $salt and $password? Can you also show the 8.3 version of $results for that same row?

Everything in that code is pretty fundamental, the only thing to suspect is that $query->getRowArray() is not returning what you expect.

Come to think of it, you're generating the salt as a binary string, so if it's not handled properly both on its trips to and from the database it may get munged in transit and differ between versions. Dump a bin2hex() of a pre-existing salt via the old and new environment to compare.

Can you add the DDL of the two database columns to your question?
